# Copy ONLY rows that are NOT blank from A1:A150 to Column B

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would greatly appreciate a solution to the following:
Copy ONLY rows that are NOT blank from A1:A150 to Column B or copy to another work sheet. As much as half of the rows can be blank in Column A.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? What research have you done? :)

Comment: How do you want the target column organised?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim K As Long, i As Long
    K = 1
    For i = 1 To 150
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Cells(i, 1).Copy Cells(K, 2)
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest searching the whole column not just from 1 to 150

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula solution:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `B1` and copy-paste/fill-down the column:

```dart
{=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$150="",FALSE,ROW($A$1:A$150)),ROW())),"")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `filter` function (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

Then make a custom filter rule to hide `texts that contain (nothing or blank)`

Apply the filter then copy paste the filtered data.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use vba to search the whole Column, this is what I would use:

```
Public Sub Copier()
Dim toRow As Integer
toRow = 1
Columns("A").Activate
For Each Value In Selection
    If Value Then
     Cells(toRow, 2).Value = Value
     toRow = toRow + 1
    End If
Next Value
End Sub
```